# How do I convert numbers into text? (In mySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to convert 0's and 1's in my table 'collection' to '0' being 'no' and '1' being 'yes' within SQL Server, I've researched various places and i still haven't found a concrete answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Change the column type to string and `UPDATE collection SET column='no' WHERE column=0;`?

Comment: Is the question about SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: This is about SQL Server, apologies I've just realised my mistake in the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  case 
    when Yourfield = 0 then 'no'
    when Yourfield = 1 then 'yes'
  end as GotIt
from
  collection
```

Comment: missing `end` `end as GotIt`

Comment: Thank you! Can I use this to select two different fields at once? For example, changing collection and dropoff?

Comment: You can add a comma after 'GotIT' and add a similar case statement for another field. The case statement just results in a calculated field value, and you can have multiple of those, and return normal fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create another field and update it with your new values.
`ALTER TABLE table1 ADD newfield VARCHAR(10);
UPDATE TABLE1 SET newfield = if(oldfield = 1, 'YES','NO');
ALTER TABLE table1 drop field oldfield;
alter table table1 rename newfield to oldfield;`

Comment: I wanted to avoid altering my tables really, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: When you said converting numbers to string I didn't understand if you want to convert your field or just create a SELECT statement.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific. The SELECT statement works although I can only do this for one field at a time or it merges the data from two fields into one, do you know how I would do this?

Comment: Give me an example about what you want to do

Comment: Okay so I need to do:


select case
when collection = 0 then 'no'
when collection = 1 then 'yes
end as collection
from enquiry

select case
when dry_drop = 0 then 'no'
when dry_drop = 1 then 'yes'
end as dry_drop
from enquiry


So the two fields are from the same table, i've tried UNION but this merges the data from both fields into the first COLLECTION field

Comment: when collection = 0 and dry_drop = 1 should it return yes or no?